# user edit page on quick tab crashes when uploading images

Tags: 7, users, blocks

I'm using quicktabs and in one of the tabs I'm using a callback the callback is the client profile2 edit page `user/%1/edit/client`

The form is correctly rendered but it crashes when I try to upload images in an image field of the profile I get the following errors

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_profile_form in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 807 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/includes/form.inc).
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'user_profile_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 842 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/includes/form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #user_category in block_form_user_profile_form_alter() (line 575 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/modules/block/block.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #user_category in profile2_form_user_profile_form_alter() (line 348 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/sites/all/modules/profile2/profile2.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in profile2_form_user_profile_form_alter() (line 348 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/sites/all/modules/profile2/profile2.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #user_category in system_form_user_profile_form_alter() (line 1968 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/modules/system/system.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #user in tse_form_alter() (line 454 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/sites/all/modules/tse/tse.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in tse_form_alter() (line 454 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/sites/all/modules/tse/tse.module).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in tse_form_alter() (line 454 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/sites/all/modules/tse/tse.module).
Notice: Undefined index: profile_client in file_ajax_upload() (line 271 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/modules/file/file.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #suffix in file_ajax_upload() (line 280 of /home4/tse/public_html/troubleshootexpress.com/modules/file/file.module).
```

I read in other topics that adding the file path would solve the problem, so I did a hook_menu_alter like this:

```
function tse_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'user');
  $items['user/%user_category/edit/client']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'user');

}
```

but it does not have any effect the menu is correctly altered but it does not fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide your `tse_form_alter` function and any other pertinent custom code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport and should be posted in appropriate issue queue, not here. Unless you can track it to something you did or something that happened on your site. It is not possible for anyone here to debug that for you.